# How to efficiently limit returned rows in SQL Server 2000 (return rows from X to Y)?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2000, paging, compatibility

I'm working on a system that has to be MS SQL Server 2000-compatible (yes, sucks, but tell that to our clients who are still using it). Anyways, I've come up against this roadblock of a situation...

There's this table that can have a lot of records in it (products table, really). One of our clients even has near to 1M records. I'm building a web shop, and need to display record from that table. Naturally, I should provide paging in the web, so I need an option to select only records from X to Y.

But how to do this in a way, that would be both efficient, and work even in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: I would love to tell the client their hardware spec sucks just drop us their details :)

Comment: @digiguru - sorry, I don't even know who they are, and I think there are several such clients, as the software we sell is quite popular in these here parts.

Answer (score 4):

The only semi-workable solution for large table on SQL Server 2000 I know of is the pattern

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
  FROM products p1
  WHERE p1.productID not in (SELECT TOP 200 productID FROM products p2)
```

This will display rows 201-300.

If ordering and filtering is required (and it usually is) you need to make sure that the order and filter is the same in both query and subquery (otherwise, the results are a bit funky), like

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
  FROM products p1
  WHERE p1.productID not in (SELECT TOP 200 productID 
                               FROM products p2 
                               WHERE p2.productGroup = 2
                               ORDER BY p2.productName)
    AND p1.productGroup = 2
  ORDER BY p1.productName
```

(this returns the 201-300 product where productGroup is 2 ordered by name).

The downside to this approach is that SQL Server 2000 does not support the `TOP @variable` syntax, so the 100 and 200 in the above query cannot be easily parametricized. To generate this query you would either have to use an SP that will use dynamic SQL, or compile it on the client application, and then sent it to the database as-is.

In an unrelated rant, I always wondered why this is not supported on the database level, for example something like

```
SELECT ROW 201-300 *
  FROM products
  WHERE....
```

as this scenario appears over and over again.

Comment: You definitely want to include ordering, even without filtering - otherwise the results can vary between page refreshes - products can appear on multiple pages, and it's just a general mess

Comment: @Damien: Actually with no ordering clause, the results should appear in the order of the clustered index (provided that the table has one). But, yes, I always use ordering just to be on the safe side.

Comment: what about other way round? `select top 100 * from (select top 300 * from products order by productID asc) p order by product_id desc` This at least doesn't use any `IN`s or other lookups.

Comment: P.S. All queries are generated on the fly by our app, so no problem with hardcoding values.

Comment: @Sweko - that's a common myth. There's no ordering guarantee without an order by clause. Among other things, in Enterprise Edition, it's possible for one table scan to "piggy back" on another one that's already in progress (for a different connection/query), and then do a partial table scan of the start of the table to get the remaining rows it hasn't obtained yet.

Comment: @Vix, I guess that would work too, but using reverse order clauses, while clever, would soon turn to be a maintenance nightmare. I would analyze the performance of both queries, and unless this pattern is much faster, I would stick with the former syntax.

Comment: @Damien: +1 Agreed, that's what I meant by 'should appear' and 'funky results', but tnx for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @SWeko - RE: Your unrelated rant this is quite easy in later versions than 2000 with `row_number` and `between` anyway and [will be made even more straightforward next version](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2011-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx)

Comment: @Marting -  I wasn't this excited as I am about Denali since the first Yukon beta, but nonetheless, this feature (along with booleans *cough*oracle*cough*) should have been designed into the language ages ago.

Answer (score 2):

SWeko has a good answer and it was my first thought.  If you didn't want to have the subquery, you could:

```
SET ROWCOUNT @Y

SELECT *
FROM products p1    
WHERE p1.productID > @X
ORDER BY p1.productID

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Although you'll have to remember @X which may not be an integer or an identity.

Comment: Is this any different from `top`?

Comment: Actually, that's an interesting idea, even with `top`. This makes it easy to walk forwards and backwards between pages, and performance is excellent. However you cannot jump to an arbitrary page, which is a drawback. Maybe this can be combined, I don't know.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 does not support the TOP @variable syntax.  But you can use SET ROWCOUNT @Y to send it as a parameter.  The top answer has a fixed 100 records.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer while searching for a similar solution:

```
SELECT
    product_name,
    list_price
FROM
    production.products
ORDER BY
    list_price,
    product_name 
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

The full explanation is available [here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/).

Comment: The problem is - this syntax was introduced in SQL Server 2012, while this question is about SQL Server 2000. :) Although for current versions, yes, that's absolutely the way to go! :)

Answer (score -1):

We have used following technique:

```
SELECT TOP @top * FROM ...
```

Where @top is equal to (Y). So only top rows are selected by SQL server, to get expected page we have used simple fetching without data extraction (until X)

Comment: Not sure, but I think `TOP @top` is a SQL Server 2005 feature.

Comment: Sorry - this isn't possible in SQL 2000.